# SQL for Aggregate 25 percentile value for subsets in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

This gets the 25th percentile value of the GM field when field GICS Sector = "Energy":

```
SELECT
  tblFirst250.[GICS Sector]
  , 0.75*(
    SELECT Max(GM) 
    FROM tblFirst250 
    WHERE tblFirst250.GM IN (
      SELECT TOP 25 PERCENT GM 
      FROM tblFirst250 
      WHERE tblFirst250.[GICS Sector ]= "Energy" AND GM Is Not Null ORDER BY GM)) + 0.25*(
        SELECT Min(GM) 
        FROM tblFirst250 
        WHERE tblFirst250.GM IN (
          SELECT TOP 75 PERCENT GM 
          FROM tblFirst250 
          WHERE tblFirst250.[GICS Sector] = "Energy" AND GM Is Not Null ORDER BY GM DESC)
  ) AS 25Percentile
FROM tblFirst250
WHERE tblFirst250.[GICS Sector] = "Energy"
GROUP BY tblFirst250.[GICS Sector];
```

...which correctly produces:

- GICS Sector, 25Percentile
- Energy, -1.2

Now I am trying to get all of the 25th percentiles for each GICS Sector. It would look something like this:

- GICS Sector, 25Percentile
- Energy, -1.2
- Industrials, [some value]
- Materials, [some value] 
  ...etc.

Here is one of my 500 attempts, which does not work correctly:

```
SELECT tbl.[GICS Sector], 0.75*(
SELECT Max(GM) 
FROM tbl 
WHERE tbl.GM IN (
SELECT TOP 25 PERCENT GM 
FROM tbl 
WHERE tbl.[GICS Sector] = tbl.[GICS Sector] AND GM Is Not Null ORDER BY GM)) + 0.25*(
SELECT Min(GM) 
FROM tbl 
WHERE tbl.GM IN (
SELECT TOP 75 PERCENT GM 
FROM tbl 
WHERE tbl.[GICS Sector] = tbl.[GICS Sector] AND GM Is Not Null ORDER BY GM DESC)
) AS 25Percentile
FROM tbl
WHERE tbl.[GICS Sector] = tbl.[GICS Sector]
GROUP BY tbl.[GICS Sector];
```

...the above results in the same value for all GICS Sectors. I want a different 25th percentile value for each GICS Sector.

Comment: Max(GM) OVER (PARTITION BY tbl.[GICS Sectror]) might lead you to what you need.

Comment: @DylanCross - I'll look into it. After looking here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx  it looks like I have quite the challenge to overcome to pull it off. If you can give any more, that would be awesome. Either way, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a similar question on another forum and got this answer:
http://www.accessforums.net/queries/sql-aggregate-25-percentile-value-subsets-ms-53125.html#post280306

...which is correct. Thank you for all your help Mark C. Hopefully this saves you some time.

Here is the guts of it, but not all of it. Basically a loop through GICS Sectors:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Function GetTop25Percent()
'MsgBox "I AM HERE"
    Call Top25PercentGroup
End Function
Sub Top25PercentGroup()
    Dim rawdata As String
    Dim desttbl As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim tmpName As String
    Dim tmpSQL As String

    rawdata = "tbl"
    desttbl = "tblTop25PCNT"

'MsgBox "I AM HERE"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "TruncateTblTop25PCNT"

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Unique GICS Sector")

'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst 'Unnecessary in this case, but still a good habit
        Do Until rs.EOF = True

            tmpName = rs("[GICS Sector]")

'Build top 25 % SQL For each GICS Sector
            tmpSQL = "INSERT INTO " & desttbl & " ( "
            tmpSQL = tmpSQL & "[GICS Sector], [GM] ) "
            tmpSQL = tmpSQL & "SELECT TOP 25 PERCENT [GICS Sector], [GM] "
            tmpSQL = tmpSQL & "FROM " & rawdata & " "
            tmpSQL = tmpSQL & "WHERE [GM] IS NOT NULL "
            tmpSQL = tmpSQL & "AND [GICS Sector] = """ & tmpName & """"

            DoCmd.RunSQL (tmpSQL)

'Move to the next record. Don't ever forget to do this.
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
'    Else
'        MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
    End If

'        MsgBox "Finished looping through records."

    rs.Close            'Close the recordset
    Set rs = Nothing    'Clean up

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```